# Not able to submit spark job from oozie

Tags: exception, oozie

I am getting below exception while triggering a spark job from oozie workflow.Any idea what may be the issue?

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application
>   application_1480735305639_6874 finished with failed status
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:940)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:986)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>               at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:185)
>               at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:176)
>               at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
>               at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:46)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>               at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:378)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:296)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Can you give any more information about what you are trying to run?  Or do you think this is a more generic problem than your specific task?

Comment: Spark simply says "YARN job failed" => did you check the YARN logs to get the actual error message??? E.g. with the command line `yarn application -status application_1480735305639_6874` then `yarn logs -applicationId application_1480735305639_6874` or using the YARN web console...

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue why it was failing for. I was new to oozie. Basically oozie has its own mapreduce wrapper process on your action. So if your action fails,it traverses till oozie wrapper. I was getting this exception because my action job was failing in turn I got this exception in map reduce wrapper. thanks